# 403 error while using htaccess to make seo friendly links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Thanks to your help guys I was able to make an .htaccess that rewrites the dynamic links into static one. Now I would like to to extend that solution onto the whole site so that I load accurate module based on $_get variable. Then thanks to .htaccess I should be able to make seo friendly links. The only issue is... it's not working... It shows me an error:

403 Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this document.

I am using this script to rewrite the links:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mod1/

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/mod1/index.php\?module=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /mod1/%1? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^mod1/([^\s&]+)?$ mod1/index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Right now I am using the folder mod1 but normally I would like to have there a domain, so that it would have:

www.domain.com/index.php?module=create_list

to be redirected to:

www.domain.com/create_list

I have found an information on the net that I should change the permissions of the file I target (which is index in my case) to 755 but it didn't work in my case.
Another mystery of that script is that the first part seems to work, but I am not sure why it always gives the url "/" at the end, even if I did not defined it in the rule.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I manage to fix that problem with mall changes to the script:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mod1/

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/mod1/index.php\?module=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=302,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/]+).html?$ index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It is working poperly. However I still do not understand few things. Firstly if I remove the # from:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

The [L,QSA] still works but the permament [R=302,L] not, I  understand that those two line are for files that are used with the php file and they fix the problem with pathways. But how to make them work together w permament redirect 302?

Second thing is I needed to add .html at the end of static link, which was not part of my plan. Is it possible to make it work without .html extension?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to have more than one variable passed from SEO url back to your index.php you could do something like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?module=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?module=$1&var2=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?module=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

**Make sure to put that .htaccess file in your mod1/ directory and remove the old one.**

If you access `/mod1/search` the request will end in `index.php?module=search`.

`/mod1/search/Books` => `index.php?module=search&var2=Books`

`mod1/search/Books/20` => `index.php?module=search&var2=Books&var3=20`

I don't see any point why you would redirect `/mod1/index.php?module=something` to `/mod1/something` because this will lead to **endless** loop:

1. User sends `/mod1/index.php?module=something` => Server redirects it to `/mod1/something`
2. User sends `/mod1/something` => Server redirects it to `/mod1/index.php?module=something`

and so on... Not to mention the duplicated content you'll end with from the search engine's point of view.

**EDIT 1:**
If you want to make the trailing slash optional, just append `/?` at the end of the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&var2=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?module=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem, as now it doesn't rewrite the the url. In addition I have an url ..mod1/index.php?module=create_list but it doesn't display the correct content. It seems as the php doesnt receive GET variable.

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Why you will need to redirect `/mod1/index.php?module=something` to `/mod1/something` anyway?

Comment: I want to have redirect the dynamic links to static to avoid duplicated content, in case someone would use that way to access it - at least that's my assumption. Is it wrong? I used your code, unfortunately it didn't solve the problem as still link: [link](/mod1/something) gives me 403 error - "Forbidden - You don't have permissions to access this document" (I have put it in the folder mod1). Is it possible that the error is related to php in the index.php that includes the file from different folder? because I am running out of ideas why this "simple" redirect is not working...

Comment: Regarding the 403 error, any new errors in apache's error.log ? In my opinion in order to avoid duplicated content, you must choose one URL style and stick to it, just redirect the other one permanently to the 'correct' version of it. This way you'll end up with one URL per page, which is the point, right?

Comment: Hey, Thats why I need the redirect to static links s that I wont have duplicated content. I edited the question because I made it working. Partialy I manage to fix the problem but do not understand few things. Could you explain to me those 2 things I added in the question?

Comment: `!-f` means - if not file; `!-d` - if not directory => if the URL is not actual FILE (e.g. javascript file, image, css etc) and not actual directory (e.g. images etc) then proceed with the other conditions. This has nothing to do with PHP itself, but is telling the apache should it rewrite `/assets/css/main.css` to `index.php?something=assets/css/main.css`, or `/images/` to `index.php?something=images` for example or not.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question, look again in my answer - there is no .html used, plus you have the ability to have more than one variable passed to your script. ;)

Comment: Hey, sorry for late I answer, yes I slove my problem thanks for help!